# Back up the whole Alfresco installation directory, hosted on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, backup, alfresco

I have an Alfresco community installation, hosted on Amazon Web Services, which I am using as a personal repository. I am starting having quite important docs stored within (roughly 2Gb), so I am thinking about how to implement a strong backup/restore strategy.
I have seen many tutorials and official docs, showing how to backup alfresco by backing up two directories, alf_data and the postgresql (or whatever database is used) directory.

The question: in the case of a default Alfresco installation, which means with an embedded database, I wonder if the following scenario is enough for being considered a good cold back up strategy. The starting point is of course stopping Alfresco, then one (or both) of the following.

- Tar gz the whole alfresco installation directory and store in a safe place (at the moment Amazon S3).
- Create an EBS snapshot with the amazon EC2 console

Comment: Where is the data stored within EC2? On a EBS, or the local disks?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by local disk (due to my lack of knowledge of AWS). I can tell you that there's a single EBS which is attached to the EC2. Everything is stored in there, kind of /opt/alfresco containing tomcat, alf_data ecc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both your alf_data and postgres directory is on the EBS, than a snapshot is sufficient.

You just need to know that a hot-backup (done while running Alfresco) could be inconstant: out of sync database & alf_data or inclomplete within a transaction.

A cold-backup is the best, take look at the [Alfresco Wiki](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Backup_and_Restore) for more info.

Still when doing a hot-backup at night when there are no jobs running (ldap/cleanup/etc) it's doable.

Comment: Thanks. In the case of a snapshot, do you think stopping alfresco is enough, or do I need to stop the whole EC2 instance before taking the EBS snapshot ? Consider that the instance is fully dedicated to Alfresco installation.

Comment: Just Alfresco is more than sufficient. Just read the linked Wiki once and maybe some things not explained will become clear.